# Removing objects inside an object

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an object (as ROI) which isn't filled. There are some smaller objects inside that object. How can I fill those objects and make it part of the big object? (Using OpenCV)
Using `morphologyEx` doesn't help me here because it effects the edge of the big object, changes the shape of the big object, and also is very slow specially when we want to fill bigger objects.
I'll put the input and desired output image here so you know what I'm looking for.
Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

I'm looking for the strategy or the code for solving this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `cv::findContours` function with `cv::RETR_TREE` to find contours in a hierarchical way (child contours). Then use `cv::fillConvexPoly` to fill the child contours. Read [this](https://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2013/01/contours-5-hierarchy.html) excellent post to better understand.

Comment: @zindarod it's better to use `fillPoly` (since the contours is not convex) or simply`drawContours(..., CV_FILLED, ...)`

Comment: see also [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/)

Comment: @Miki You're right. I was distracted.

Comment: @Miki The drawContours technique is faster than the floodFill technique. Works great.